# Trying to write this excel function in JS but stump on the modulus portion

Tags: javascript, modulo

Here is the excel function and it works fine in excel.

`lng = mod(lng1-asin(sin(tc1)*sin(d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi`

I am trying to convert it to JavaScript,  I have this so far but it is not working.

```
    x = lng1-Math.asin(Math.sin(tc1)*Math.sin(d));
    y = Math.asin(Math.cos(lat)+Math.PI,2*Math.PI);
    n = (x % y)-Math.PI ;
```

I am passing the coordinates in radians (and verified they are correct as in the example below) but just can't figure out why its giving me NaN

TIA for the help

Steve

This is the worked example ( from here https://edwilliams.org/avform.htm#Intermediate)

````
         = mod(2.066470- asin(sin(1.150035)*sin(0.0290888)/cos(0.604180))+pi,2*pi)-pi
         = mod(2.034206+pi,2*pi)-pi radians
         = 2.034206 radians
         = 116 degrees 33min```
````

Comment: If you're getting `NaN`, it means that one or more of the inputs (the variables) are not numbers.

Comment: Convert your variable to numbers using `Number(<var>)` when input can be variable.

Comment: what is Math.lgn1 ? are you setting that property on the root Math object?

Comment: yes lng1 is set by lng1=degToRad(lng1);  There is a mistake in x it should not ne Math.lng1 just lng1- but still ends up with nan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some minor conversion mistakes you've made in your conversion. In order to  allow the code to correctly work, below is my solution:

```js
const result = lng1 - Math.asin((Math.sin(tc1) * Math.sin(d)) / Math.cos(lat)) +  Math.PI % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

The solution may look a bit long, but it functions just as normal and completes the operation in the exact order.

Given that:

```
let lng1 = 2.06647;
let tc1 = 1.150035;
let d = 0.0290888;
let lat = 0.60418;
```

The code will execute and the final constant named `result` will have a value of 2.0342057088546213, or around 2.034206, **in radians**. If there is any need of conversions to degrees, simply multiply the result by a factor of 57.295779513082 since **1 radian is equal to 57.295779513082 degrees**.